# Taking snapshot of contents in CGL?

Tags: macos, opengl, core-graphics, cglayer

I want to create a image out of Core OpenGL context.

I used following code but it creates a black image. So I guess I cannot use glReadPixles there? Any other suggestions please?

```
int myDataLength = 480 * 480 * 4;
// allocate array and read pixels into it.
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, 320, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
    // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
// there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
for(int y = 0; y < 480; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 320 * 4; x++)
    {
        buffer2[(479 - y) * 320 * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * 320 + x];
    }
}

// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * 320;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

// make the cgimage
CGImageRef image= CGImageCreate(320, 480, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, false, renderingIntent);

//PRINT image... Its black!!!!!!

CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
free(buffer);
free(buffer2);
```

Comment: I don't know about the CGImage things(never used them), but glReadPixels certainly works with a CGLContextObj aswell. are you setting anything with glReadBuffer before calling glReadPixels, are you properly binding the Context, maybe you should show some more code about what you are doing before calling glReadPixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do a glReadPixels call you must

- set proper packing (see *glPixelStorei* reference page)
- select the right buffer to read from with *glReadBuffer* (front after swapping, back before swapping, I recommend swap and read from front)